# HTML5/CSS3 - div id not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an image in my body, using a div id with a background image. I don't understand why the image isn't showing up when i preview in google chrome?

I am using almost the same code on my index page and it's working fine there.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="body">

<div id="rainforestimage"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#body {
width:1024px;
height:auto;
background-image:url(../images/background2.png);
margin:0 auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
}

#rainforestimage {
background-image:url(../images/exhibits/rainforest.png);
width:1024px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:74px;
height:364px;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
}
```

Comment: get rid of the div and just set it to the body tag

Comment: Try setting `overflow` to `auto` in your `#body`

Comment: why you are using position:absolute in #rainforestimage, is it necessary?

Comment: only because nothing in your `<div id="body">` you  given `position:absolute;` for `#rainforestimage`

Comment: See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/jhwzfdLb/

Answer (score 1):

Your `div#body` needs to have a height set, try setting a height and you will see your background image.

Also your HTML page and the folder **images** should be siblings (same level) in the same directory.

EDIT:

If you still don't see **background2.png**, it's because **rainforest.png** is covering it(on top of it) because of the other styles you have set:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
```

Comment: Oh, I should specify that it's "rainforest.png" which isn't showing :)

Comment: @Tasos Thanks for the edit, I want to do better at editing Q&A's. seeing my answer edited shows me what I can do to achieve my goal, thanks!

Comment: @QueenOfRome, maybe silly question but have to rule it out... Is there a folder named: 'exhibits' containing "rainforest.png" inside your images folder ? (check spelling)

Answer (score 0):

Div with position absolute ideally takes 0 height. you need to set height either 100%, or `top:0` & `bottom:0` .

Try using following CSS code.

```
#rainforestimage {
  background-image:url(../images/exhibits/rainforest.png);
  width:1024px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:74px;
  height:364px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not able to see it because the height wasn't set.
Added in CSS

```
#body {
width:1024px;
height:200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/72wr5n7u/

The image overlaps, you can set the margin according to your image.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping same width for `#body` and `#rainforestimage`,and for `#body` you are having `height:auto`,if you have only one div `#rainforestimage` under `#body` then ideally body width will be same as of `#rainforestimage` div,so no point you can see the background image.
so if you need increese the `height` of the div `#body` and reduce the `width` of your `#rainforestimage`,so that you can see the background image.

this will work for sure.
If you are facing any layering issues,Use `z-index`,make sure that the element is having `position` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding min-height to div #body. actually #body won't have height because the element #rainforestimage you placed inside is positioned absolute.

```
#body {
  min-height:364px;
}
```